# How to compare hash of an image using python and unity3d C#?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, hash, md5

I have a unity3d application that request a json string of image name including its hash in my django webserver. Then my unity app will check my existing image hash if its the same as the json requested. My problem is that unity hash result is different from my python hash result value. I also tried to hash string on both and it returns the same hash value.

Python Hash:

```
>>> image_file = open('C:/image.png').read()
>>> hashlib.md5(image_file).hexdigest()
'658e8dc0bf8b9a09b36994abf9242099'
```

Unity3d Hash:

```
public static string ComputeHash()
{
    // Form hash
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 h =System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    var myImage = File.OpenRead(PathByPlatform("image.png"));
    var data = h.ComputeHash(myImage );

    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
    {
        sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();

    //This fucntion returns 
    //fac7f19792a696d81be77aca7dd499d0
}
```

Comment: could it be an encoding problem? Did you try using `System.Convert.ToString(data[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0')` instead of of using `ToString("x2")` directly? Also I'm not sure but I guess `ComputeHash` already returns in hexadecimal so you are doing it twice using `"x2"` again?

Comment: @derHugo I tried what you suggested but it returns the same value "fac7f19792a696d81be77aca7dd499d0"

Comment: Took it from the [Unify Community Wiki](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MD5)

Comment: Did you try:
`open('C:/image.png', "rb").read()`

if this doesn't work, could you post a png image and tell us the results you get. or tell us for example what md5sums you get for following png file? (This is just a random png, that I found on the net and which is free of copyright https://img.pngio.com/idea-svg-png-icon-free-download-279397-onlinewebfontscom-idea-png-free-981_946.png )

With given data we don't know which md5sum is wrong

Comment: Thanks @gelonida it did return the same hash value. So the c# code is returning the correct hash. Regarding the image you linked, it returns 478b3711f0fecda488a9f95ac0b9a6c8 in both language. Can you make your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: yes can confirm that 478b3711f0fecda... is the right hash (tested with posix md5sum command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `open('C:/image.png', "rb").read()` in order to read the file in binary mode?

Reading files without the "b" will change line ending characters on Windows from CR/LF to LF which has an impact on the hash. (at least for python2)